# Python library to simulate keyboard/mouse input on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, x11

I am looking to make a Python script that can "press" keys and move the cursor to an arbitrary position on the screen on my linux pc. Is there one that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Xdotool do what you expect, but on command line, not in python.